Livewire method not being called
I'm encountering an issue with my Livewire component where a method call is not being triggered.
I have a Livewire component in my Laravel project that includes a button with a wire:click directive bound to a method called showEventDay(). However, when I click the button, the method does not seem to be called, even though I've verified that the Livewire component is properly initialized and the method is defined correctly.
My blade file
<div class="bg-white border-2 border-slate-200 rounded-b-lg p-4 w-full">
                <div class="mt-0">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <div class="bg-white w-full  max-h-85 rounded-lg">  
                            <div>
                                <button id="eventDayButton" wire:click="showEventDay(1)" onclick="console.log('Button clicked')" class="relative rounded px-5 py-2.5 overflow-hidden bg-green-500 relative hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-green-500 hover:to-green-400 text-white hover:ring-2 hover:ring-offset-2 hover:ring-green-400 transition-all ease-out duration-300;" >
                                    {{ __('Add new event day') }}
                                </button>   
                                @livewire('admin.event-days.edit', ['event' => $event])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>

My Component:
namespace App\Livewire\Admin\EventDays;

use Livewire\Component;

class Edit extends Component
{
    public $event;
    public $visible = 0;
    
    public function showEventDay($value)
    {
        $this->visible = $value;
          
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.events.editEvent');
    }
}

Environment Details:
Laravel version: 11.0.5
Livewire version: 3.4.8

When you have your console open, do you see a request fired in the networks tab?

I had style tag inside my blade (styling for my modal) . So when I removed it, it started working. I did't understand what was the issue. Any idea?

A livewire view can only have a single root element.
